# Navigation changed in react native

Tags: react-native, parameters, react-navigation, react-props

I have changed from the this navigation

```
"react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
```

to

```
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
```

But the problem is now app is crashing due to

```
props.navigation?.state?.params?.data
```

Above route params are working in the whole app so anyone can let me know how can i resolve it. So i got all the params with less changes. As these are changed in both versions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below code,

```js
function DetailsScreen({ route, navigation }) {
    const {itemId} = route.params;
}
```

--------------OR----------------

using hooks

```js
import {useRoute} from '@react-navigation/core';
function DetailsScreen({ route, navigation }) {
    const route = useRoute();
    const {itemId} = route.params;
}
```